# Appending data to a file on a FTP server in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp, cfstream

After learning the basics from Apple's SimpleFTPSample project, I'm trying to **append** a string to the end of a .txt file on my FTP server. I successfully managed to overwrite an existing file with a custom string, but I suspect that the **kCFStreamPropertyAppendToFile** property that defines whether the file will be overwritten or appended is not available in iOS.

What is the recommended way to do so in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up downloading the file's content using HTTP (it's much faster than FTP). Next, appending the string to the file's content and then uploading the file to the server using FTP.
This might not be the best solution, but it does solve the problem.